# Autofill in a record based on a combobox selection in a subform

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying autofill a record based on the combobox selection.

Code

```
Private Sub SupplierName_Change()
Me.RecordSource = "Select * From Suppliers Where DetailID=" & SupplierName.Column(1)
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

When you select a record based on the combobox selection it must autofill in the record in the subform

Error im getting please advise. Thanks in advance

> Run time error '3075'
>
> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expresion DetailID =',

Comment: What happens if you write `MsgBox(SupplierName.Column(1))` on the line before?

Comment: Another option to get the data as @vityaya suggest is `debug.print SupplierName.Column(1)`

Comment: Note that `.Column` is 0-based. If you want to select the first column, that's `SupplierName.Column(0)`

Comment: hi Vityata the msgbox shows nothing shows a empty msgbox

Comment: im trying to autofill in the Last Name and First Name based on the combobox  in the subform

Comment: `DetailID` sounds like a number type, is it? I also suspect that `SupplierName.Column(1)` may be a string type?

Comment: Hi LiamH DetailID is a autonumber type its the primary key and SupplierName.Column(1) is a string

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your SQL statement:

"Select * From Suppliers Where DetailID= (" & SupplierName.Column(1) & ");"